# RankNTypes with type aliases confusion

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, higher-rank-types

I'm trying to understand how type constraints work with type aliases. First, let's assume I have next type alias:

```
type NumList a = Num a => [a]
```

And I have next function:

```
addFirst :: a -> NumList a -> NumList
addFirst x (y:_) = x + y
```

This function fails with next error:

```
Type.hs:9:13: error:
    • No instance for (Num a) arising from a pattern
      Possible fix:
        add (Num a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            addFirst :: a -> NumList a -> a
    • In the pattern: y : _
      In an equation for ‘addFirst’: ad
```

Which is obvious. This problem already described here:

[Understanding a rank 2 type alias with a class constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585220/understanding-a-rank-2-type-alias-with-a-class-constraint)

And I understand why we need `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}` for such type aliases to work and why previous example doesn't work. But what I don't understand is why next example compiles fine (on ghc 8):

```
prepend :: a -> NumList a -> NumList a
prepend = (:)
```

Of course it fails in `ghci` if I try to pass wrong value:

```
λ: prepend 1 []
[1]
λ: prepend "xx" []

<interactive>:3:1: error:
    • No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from a use of ‘prepend’
    • When instantiating ‘it’, initially inferred to have
      this overly-general type:
        NumList [Char]
      NB: This instantiation can be caused by the monomorphism restriction.
```

Seems like type type checking delayed at runtime :(

Moreover, some simple and seems to be the same piece of code doesn't compile:

```
first :: NumList a -> a
first = head
```

And produces next error:

```
Type.hs:12:9: error:
    • No instance for (Num a)
      Possible fix:
        add (Num a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            first :: NumList a -> a
    • In the expression: head
      In an equation for ‘first’: first = head
```

Can somebody explain what is going on here? I expect some consistency in whether function type checks or not.

Comment: Just think of `Num a => a` as a function `NumDict a -> a` and it should all be clear.

Comment: Though you had already linked to the question suggested by @Alec , it is worth pointing out that the second answer there (the one by luqui) is probably clearer than the accepted one in showing why `prepend` works and the other functions don't (in short, the compiler can only move the constraint to where you want it to be if you have the synonym at the rightmost position of the signature). By the way, note there is nothing strange or "delayed" in your usage examples of `prepend` -- it is doing exactly what you would expect a `Num a => a -> [a] -> [a]` function to do.

Comment: Yes, luqui's answer on the linked question is exactly relevant.

Comment: Oops! I had not intended to just link back to the same question you had linked - it was indeed luqui's answer I thought was pertinent.

Comment: @duplode Yeah, second answer by @luqui makes now everything clear. Seems like type checking depends on whether my type-aliased argument on covariant position or contravariant. I understood earlier only why `foo :: forall a . a -> (forall b . b)` is the same as `foo :: forall a b . a -> b`. But now I see that such rules also spreads on constraints if you represent them as dictionaries. Now it seems quite elegant :)

Comment: @Shersh Playing with your question made me stumble upon something that seems genuinely strange, and to [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40273246/2751851).

Answer (score 1):

> Seems like type type checking delayed at runtime :(

Not really. Here it's may be a bit surprising because you get the type error in ghci *after* having loaded the file. However it can be explained: the file itself is perfectly fine but that does not mean that *all* the expressions you can build up using the functions defined in it will be well-typed.

Higher-rank polymorphism has nothing to do with it. `(+)` for instance is defined in the prelude but if you try to evaluate `2 + "argh"` in ghci, you'll get a type-error too:

```
No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from a use of ‘+’
In the expression: 2 + "argh"
In an equation for ‘it’: it = 2 + "argh"
```

Now, let's see what the problem is with `first`: it claims that given a `NumList a`, it can produce an `a`, no questions asked. But we know how to build `NumList a` out of thin air! Indeed the `Num a` constraints means that `0` is an `a` and makes `[0]` a perfectly valid `NumList a`. Which means that if `first` were accepted then *all* the types would be inhabited:

```
first :: NumList a -> a
first = head

elt :: a
elt = first [0]
```

In particular [Void](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.7.1/docs/Data-Void.html) would be too:

```
argh :: Void
argh = elt
```

Argh indeed!

Comment: > that does not mean that all the expressions you can build up using the functions defined in it will be well-typed.
Yeah, that is a good point. I understood only after some thinking and observing error.